# How to merge 2 items in a list that are the same item but with different quantities into one that has the sum of the quantities

Tags: c#

I have 2 Item objects in my list that have the same id but different quantities, is there a way to merge them into one Item that will have the sum of both Item quantities?

Comment: Group the items by `Id`, then for each group, select a new item with the group key as the `Id`, and the group sum for the properties you want to combine. Posting a sample of your class and what you've done so far will help get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the items by `Id`, then for each group, select a new item with the group key as the `Id`, and the group sum for the properties you want to combine. Posting a sample of your class and what you've done so far would be helpful, but here's a sample.

First the `Item` class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Then a list of items:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item {Id = 1, Qty = 5},
    new Item {Id = 1, Qty = 2},
    new Item {Id = 1, Qty = 3},
    new Item {Id = 2, Qty = 2},
    new Item {Id = 2, Qty = 1},
    new Item {Id = 3, Qty = 9},
};
```

Now, here's how to group them by the `Id` and select a new item for each group that contains the `Id` as well as a sum of the `Quantity` property:

```
var combinedItems = items
    .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
    .Select(group => new Item {Id = group.Key, Qty = group.Sum(item => item.Qty)})
    .ToList();
```

**Output**

```
combinedItems.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine($"Id: {item.Id}, Qty: {item.Qty}"));
```

[image]

---

If you have  a class with other properties that you want to include that *aren't* ones that get aggregated, then we can use the `First` item in the group to set those.

For example, let's say our class has a `Name` property (which should be the same across all instances) and a `Price` property (which may or may not be the same, so we want to take the `Average`):

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, we use the `First` item for the `Name` property, and the `Average` method for the `Price`, like so:

```
var combinedItems = items
    .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
    .Select(group => new Item
    {
        Id = group.Key,                             // Key is the property we grouped by
        Name = group.First().Name,                  // Get the Name from the First item
        Price = group.Average(item => item.Price),  // Average the Price
        Qty = group.Sum(item => item.Qty)           // Sum the quantity
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you and what if I have more properties in the object and want them to be added to the new generated item?

Comment: If you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61417486/edit) your question to include the class (showing the properties), I will update the answer to use that instead. But the short answer is, grab the first one from the group for "common" properties and use those values when creating the new item, and use `Sum` (or `Average`, or whatever you want) for other properties that you want to "merge".